# How to delete a particular comment?

Tags: support, comment

I posted a comment on the question "best cities for mathematical study" but instead of providing the person who asked the question with an hyperlink that redirects one to a google maps area (in an attempt to be funny) a very long name of the link is given, and I can't delete it for some reason (I guess because it's 'below' other text of the webpage). Could a moderator please delete that comment? It can be recognized easily. Side question: is it even possible to include a hyperlink in a comment? If not, perhaps it would be a good idea to implement it as an extra feature to make this website even cooler?

Answer (score 2):

1. You could delete a comment by mouse-over to it and click on the "×".

   [image]
2. Use Mark-down to format a link.

   > `[text](http://www.example.com)`
   >
   > [text](http://www.example.com)

Comment: Max Muller might be running into [this bug](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1071/layout-bug-comments-overflow-into-rhs-pane), which would make it hard to click the "×".

Comment: @ Rahul Narain: true!